# NavigatorView's page stack is empty back to main page Onsen UI

Tags: javascript, angularjs, onsen-ui

hallo i am new with Onsen UI Framework. Very nice framework and beautiful. But i have problem with navigation. From main page to another template, in this template i type some data and save it, then automacally back again to main page. I am using myNavigator.popPage(). i have error NavigatorView's page stack is empty. here my code i am using sliding menu

Index.html

```
    <ons-navigator title="Navigator" var="myNavigator">
          <ons-sliding-menu close-on-tap
                          main-page="main.html"
                          menu-page="menu.html"       
                          side="left"
                          max-slide-distance="250px"
                          var="menu">
        </ons-sliding-menu>
  </ons-navigator>


 <ons-template id="menu.html">      
  <ons-list>
    <ons-list-item modifier="chevron" onclick="menu.setMainPage('nomor.html', {closeMenu: true})">
      Setting Nomor
    </ons-list-item>
  </ons-list>
</ons-template>


<ons-template id="nomor.html">
    <ons-page ng-controller="penomoranController">
    <ons-toolbar>
      <div class="left">
        <ons-toolbar-button ng-click="menu.toggleMenu()"><ons-icon icon="ion-navicon" style="font-size: 32px; width: 1em;"></ons-icon></ons-toolbar-button> 
    </div>
      <div class="center"> Setting Nomor</div>

      <div class="right">
        <div id="prosesAjax"></div>
      </div>

    </ons-toolbar>

        <ons-list>
            <ons-list-item>
                <input type="text" placeholder="nomor" ng-model="noini"  class="text-input text-input--transparent" style="margin-top:8px; width: 100%;">
            </ons-list-item>
        </ons-list>

        <div class="content-padded">
        <ons-button id="btnSignIn" modifier="large"  ng-click="saveData()">
          Save
        </ons-button>
      </div>
  </ons-page>
</ons-template>
```

AngularJS Controller

```
agendaApp.controller('penomoranController',function ($scope){
                 $scope.saveData=function(){
                            $scope.myNavigator.popPage();
                 };


     });
```

the problem is when i clicked Save Button get error NavigatorView's page stack is empty, what's wrong? Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 1):

`menu.setMainPage` is setting up a new stack, So in your case there is only one page (nomor.html) in the myNavigator stack. so when you try to `popPage` there is no other page to go back.

Solution - Try `myNavigator.pushPage(nomor.html)` so `myNavigator` stack push the `nomor.html` to its stack. Then you can `popPage`.